# is there any disadvantage using c++ for constants in objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c

```
//header-file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
extern UIColor *const COLOR_BACKGROUND;

//implementation-file
#import "Constants.h"
UIColor *const COLOR_BACKGROUND= [UIColor greenColor];
```

If you try this with a .m file you will get an error because it's not a compile-time constant. Changing the implementation file to .mm resolves this problem. 
But are there any quirks i should be aware of (i'm pretty clueless about c++, and i didn't see anyone doing this)?

Comment: Many developers call Objective-C++ an "unholy mariage of C++ and Objective-C". Well, I think they must be at least partly right.

Comment: It's a slippery slope.  First you just want to statically allocate some object... next thing you know you're using templates and smoking crack in alleys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there are two disadvantages:

#### 1. Initialization order

A well known problem of static initializers in C++ is initialization order. This would probably be no big deal when working with colors or fonts. But as soon as you own objects are involved it could quickly become a mess, when the constructor of one instance accesses another static object.

#### 2. Objective-C++ itself

If you use this style you are bound to Objective-C++. Not using (pure) Objective-C is awkward and error-prone when working together with other developers or using code from somewhere else. There are a lot of subtle differences between the two languages and many of them will come and bite you, especially if you are not very experienced with both languages.

There are definitely scenarios where it's worthwhile to use Objective-C++ but I wouldn't use it just for convenience.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: if i debug, i get a this
(CoreFoundation`__HALT:
0x1686880:  int3   
0x1686881:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
then it continues or crashes

Comment: If you do `po $eax` in the debug window at that point you should get the exception.  Make sure you're in the frame at the top (bottom?) of the stack.

Comment: @jeffamaphone thats the funny part if i do that i get "$0 = 23619712 [no Objective-C description available]" as description

Answer (score 1):

The arguments against this would be based on style.  Functionally, it will work as you'd expect it would, and the pitfalls that exist, are the same as they would be if you were programming pure C++ code...

Quirk you should be aware of: The wrath of the Objective-C gods, and any of your superiors who know Objective-C.

May I recommend the [CIColor colorWithString:(NSString *)], and storing your constant color as an NSString as the Objective-C way of accomplishing what it is you wish to accomplish.  Note, that the UIColor class has an initWithCIColor method.  You could use this line of logic to create local constant variables of UIColors, and appease the Objective-C overlords.

Like SO:

```
//.h
extern NSString *const COLOR_STRING;

//.m
NSString *const COLOR_STRING = @"SOME_COLOR";

@implementation ModalDelegate

- (id)init
{
    CIColor *const MY_COLOR = [CIColor colorWithString:COLOR_STRING];//Can easily be made a UIColor instead, though unfortunately there is no "UIColor fromString" method.
    self = [super init];    
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You could do (as I have done in the past): `[[UIColor class] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(COLOR_STRING)]`...